# Angular 8 and Materalize Issue

Tags: angular

All,

I am not able to build my angular 8 projects and I keep getting the below errors. I have already added ngx-materialize dependencies. Is there anything else that needs to be done so that the values are correctly pulled up from the dependencies.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/component/appraisal/list.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

        @media #{$small-and-down} {
                                ^
      Undefined variable: "$small-and-down".
      in src\app\component\appraisal\list.component.scss (line 31, column 34)
ERROR in ./lib/scss/userView.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

        color: $clr-prm !important;
              ^
      Undefined variable: "$clr-prm".
      in lib\scss\userView.scss (line 19, column 16)
ERROR in ./src/app/component/search-results/search-results.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

        color: $clr-prm;
              ^
      Undefined variable: "$clr-prm".
      in \src\app\component\search-results\search-results.component.scss (line 38, column 16)
ERROR in ./lib/scss/nav.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    @include no-select();
            ^
      No mixin named no-select
      in \lib\scss\nav.scss (line 3, column 14)
ERROR in ./lib/scss/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    @media #{$small-and-down} {
                            ^
      Undefined variable: "$small-and-down".
      in \lib\scss\styles.scss (line 22, column 30)
ERROR in ./src/app/component/appraisal/view.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    @media #{$small-and-down} {
                            ^
      Undefined variable: "$small-and-down".
      in \src\app\component\appraisal\view.component.scss (line 56, column 30)
ERROR in ./src/app/userView.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    @media #{$small-and-down} {
                            ^
      Undefined variable: "$small-and-down".
      in \src\app\userView.component.scss (line 5, column 30)
ERROR in ./src/app/component/appraisal/edit.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    background-color: $clr-gray;
                     ^
      Undefined variable: "$clr-gray".
      in \src\app\component\appraisal\edit.component.scss (line 2, column 23)
```

The contents of my angular.json are:

```
{ 
   "build":{ 
      "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options":{ 
         "outputPath":"dist/Appraisal",
         "index":"src/index.html",
         "main":"src/main.ts",
         "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
         "tsConfig":"tsconfig.app.json",
         "aot":false,
         "assets":[ 
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets"
         ],
         "styles":[ 
            "src/styles.css",
            "src/scss/_global/variables/_colors.scss",
            "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"
         ],
         "scripts":[ 
            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

My Packge.json looks like this

```
 {
    "name": "appraisal",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
        "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^3.0.3",
        "natives": "^1.1.6",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
        "ngx-materialize": "^6.1.3",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.23",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.7.2",
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.42",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
        "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
        "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
        "font-awesome-webpack": "^0.0.5-beta.2",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.0",
        "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
        "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
        "postcss-discard-duplicates": "^2.1.0",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^3.2.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
        "pump": "^1.0.2",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
        "run-sequence": "^2.2.0",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "sass-resources-loader": "1.2.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
        "webpack": "^4.8.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
    }
}
```

Update:

```
@media #{$small-and-down}  is supposed to come from materalize scss
$clr-gray is defined in my _color.scss
```

both of these files are referenced in my angular.json

Update 2:

I added both the file's now in the other scss files using the relative path something like this

```
@import '../../../scss/_global/variables/colors.scss';
@import '../../../../node_modules/materialize-css/scss/materialize.scss';
```

Does the trick. Thnks

Comment: You have some undefined variables in **list.component.scss**, make sure you declared those or if you have separate file of variables import it.

Comment: Seems like you need to import one of scss from materialize which has this CSS variables in it. See if this helps: https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass/issues/109

Comment: @media #{$small-and-down}  is supposed to come from materalize scss
$clr-gray is defined in my _color.scss
both of these files are referenced in my angular.json